# Shaky animation while changing UITableViewCell height on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uianimation

UITableView cell height change has shaky animation on iPad and iPhone 6S but works fine on iPhone 6. I have UIImageView (3/4 ratio) in side UITableView cell with dynamic cell heigh (code below). I want to fit the image with full width on any device type.

At this moment, my code works on all devices. The problem is on iPad and iPhone 6 Plus the height change animation is not smooth. On iPhone 6, its smooth. So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or what I should do to make the cell height change animation work fine on all devices?

I am using the following code:

```
// Using PFQueryTableViewController
 let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
    var SelectedCellHeight = CGFloat() 
    var UnselectedCellHeight = CGFloat() 
  ....

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

// This is how I am currently checking the tableView cell height on tap.
        if screenSize.width > 700 {
            SelectedCellHeight = 1000.0
            UnselectedCellHeight = 778.0
        } else {
            SelectedCellHeight = 522.0
            UnselectedCellHeight = 320.0
        }
        print(screenSize.width)
        print(screenSize.height)   
    }



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return SelectedCellHeight
        }
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DataViewTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = DataViewTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

        let sTap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "sTap")
        sTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(sTap)


        // Display main image
        let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "DefaultImage")
        cell.postPicture.image = initialThumbnail

        if let thumbnail = object?["postOriginalPicture"] as? PFFile {
            cell.postPicture.file = thumbnail
            cell.postPicture.loadInBackground()  
        }
        return cell
    }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DataViewTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = DataViewTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
 customNSIndexPath = indexPath
}


func sTap() {  // Tap code to increases height of tableView cell

    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil

        } else {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure why you access a cell inside your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, that code should go in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. To update the size of a cell, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for the appropriate indexPaths (both the old and the new ones).

Comment: @fishinear Thank you. I completely messed up the first post during edit. Just edited by adding my cell for row. Sorry. But this is what my current setup is when I am seeing issues with visible frames during cell height increase and decrease. This happens only on iPad/iPhone 6s. On iPhone 6 it works smoothly. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Or what would be  the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are still some strange things in your code, I am not sure whether they explain the behaviour that you describe, but here they go:

1. There is no need to register your own gesture recogniser for
   selections, the table view does that on its own when you have set
   the `allowsSelection` property.
2. If you do want to use your own gesture recogniser for some reason, 
   add it to the cell only once; don't add an additional one every time
   the cell is reused.
3. The dequeue'ing/creation of a cell
   in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not serve any purpose
4. The
   `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` combi without anything between them does
   not do anything. They are only needed when you want to apply
   multiple changes to the table, all based on the old indices and with
   combined animations
5. You still need to call
   `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to tell the table that the cells have changed size.
   Do that in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, with both the old and the new
   selection indexPaths.

See also [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs: Well, I have removed my data part in most of the code and made it simple to focus on solving the problem. Which has created some issues of it own. To answer your points, 1, 2, 5: I am using gesture recogniser because I need the double tap functionality (It was next to impossible to get double tap inside didSelectRowAtIndexPart property). 3. Yes, I should have removed that, was using it to test something with editActionsForRowAtIndexPath which will be my next question. 4. I never played around with height. I should seriously consider looking at Apple guide. Thanks.